# Return IQueryable from EF proxy object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Imagine I have the following `DbSet`:

```
public class X {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Y> YCollection { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to retrieve item 1 of `X` I execute `DbSet<X>.Find(1);` which returns me an EF proxy object.

Now that this proxy object (`X`) contains multiply `Y`'s I'd like to retrieve `YCollection` as a `IQueryable<Y>`. (Mainly to do some additional filtering on it before retrieving it from the database.)

How can I retrieve `YCollection` as `IQueryable<Y>`?

Comment: IQueryable<YCollection> or IQueryable<Y>?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Got confused, edited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this directly off the entity itself that I'm aware of, but you can use the context itself to form the query:

```
var x = context.DbSet<X>.Find(1);

var query = context.Entry(x).Collection(x => YCollection).Query();
```

I suppose this could be wrapped up in an extension method to be used like:

```
x.YCollection.AsQueryable(context);
```

Comment: Implemented this with the help of some reflection and works like a charm!

Comment: There's `A` way to do this?  Or there's `NO` way to do this... You can't just leave out words man.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the LINQ extension methode for this:

```
using System.Linq;

//....

x.YCollection.AsQueryable();
```

But then it would execute as LINQ to Objects instead of LINQ to Entities. So you could use this if you just needed a IQueryable object instead of needing it for performance issues.

Comment: This doesn't allow him to filter the collection on the database; this is doing it client side.

Comment: Helped me through the weekend! :D